# Annotations, Annotations, Annotations

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

So `MKAnnotation's. Fun stuff.

My questions:

What's the difference between an annotation's title and its subtitle and how does that affect the visual component of the annotation?

What's the difference between a `MKPinAnnotationView` and a `MKAnnotationView`?
Are there different types of map annotations in iOS apart from pins?

Comment: wow! 2 in 1 ! see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935642/should-i-use-mkannotation-mkannotationview-or-mkpinannotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Title` is main heading of your pin.

The `subtitle` is actually displaying the address/(common info) of the dropped pin.You can store other deeply information of related to **title** that is puted on pin.

[image]

`MKAnnotation` is a protocol you need to adopt if you wish to show your object on a `MKMapView`. The coordinate property tells `MKMapView` where to place it. title and subtitle properties are optional but if you wish to show a callout view you are expected to implement title at a minimum.

`MKAnnotationView` visually presents the `MKAnnotation` on the `MKMapView`. The image property can be set to determine what to show for the annotation. However you can subclass it and implement `drawRect:` yourself.

`MKPinAnnotationView` is a subclass of `MKAnnotationView` that uses a Pin graphic as the image property. You can set the pin color and drop animation.

Don't forget about the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` and the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` properties of `MKAnnotationView` that can be used to customize the callout view.

Answer (score 2):

The title and subtitle are displayed when a pin is selected on the map.   The subtitle simply falls below the title.

`MKPinAnnotationView` is simply an specialized form of `MKAnnotationView` that knows how to draw a pin (and a shadow) and also allows setting the pin color.  It's the only built-in annotation view with an image, you have to make your own if you want something different (but it's very easy to do).

Comment: You'll need to make sure `canShowCallout = YES;` in order for anything to appear when the user touches the annotation.